# NFS kerberos not working

Tags: nfs, kerberos

I'm trying to authenticate to another server with kerberos and I'm getting the following response:

```
[root@ip-10-1-5-59 nfs-test-1]#  mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5  kbserver.example.com:/ /home/ec2-user/nfs-test-1 --verbose
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Thu Aug 23 00:59:58 2018
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.1,addr=10.1.5.21,clientaddr=10.1.5.59'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.0,addr=10.1.5.21,clientaddr=10.1.5.59'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting kbserver.example.com:/
```

If I tail `/var/log/messages` I see the following log, but not sure if this is relevant.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-1-5-21 anypoint-nfs-share]$ sudo tail -f /var/log/messages | grep warn
Aug 23 00:59:28 localhost kernel: NFSD: warning: no callback path to client Linux NFSv4.1 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal: error -22
```

In my client, the `klist -ke` outputs the following:

```
[root@ip-10-1-5-59 nfs-test-1]# klist -ke
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   8 host/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   8 host/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   8 host/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des3-cbc-sha1)
   8 host/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   8 host/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia256-cts-cmac)
   8 host/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia128-cts-cmac)
   8 host/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-hmac-sha1)
   8 host/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   7 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   7 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   7 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des3-cbc-sha1)
   7 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   7 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia256-cts-cmac)
   7 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia128-cts-cmac)
   7 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-hmac-sha1)
   7 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   8 host/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   8 host/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   8 host/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des3-cbc-sha1)
   8 host/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   8 host/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia256-cts-cmac)
   8 host/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia128-cts-cmac)
   8 host/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-hmac-sha1)
   8 host/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   8 nfs/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   8 nfs/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   8 nfs/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des3-cbc-sha1)
   8 nfs/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   8 nfs/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia256-cts-cmac)
   8 nfs/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia128-cts-cmac)
   8 nfs/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-hmac-sha1)
   8 nfs/kbserver.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
   8 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   8 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   8 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des3-cbc-sha1)
   8 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (arcfour-hmac)
   8 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia256-cts-cmac)
   8 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (camellia128-cts-cmac)
   8 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-hmac-sha1)
   8 nfs/kbclient.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM (des-cbc-md5)
```

---

The following nfs/rpc services are enabled in my server:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-1-5-21 ~]$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep -E "(nfs|rpc)"
nfs-server.service                            enabled
nfs.service                                   enabled
rpcbind.service                               enabled
rpcbind.socket                                enabled
nfs-client.target                             enabled
```

And the following nfs/rpc services are enabled in my client:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-1-5-59 nfs-test-1]$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep -E "(nfs|rpc)"
rpcbind.service                               enabled
rpcbind.socket                                enabled
nfs-client.target                             enabled
```

---

Just noticed that the following is throwing an error:

```
[root@ip-10-1-5-59 nfs-test-1]# sudo systemctl status nfs-secure.service
● rpc-gssd.service - RPC security service for NFS client and server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpc-gssd.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-08-23 00:35:16 UTC; 31min ago
 Main PID: 32200 (rpc.gssd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rpc-gssd.service
           └─32200 /usr/sbin/rpc.gssd -vvv

Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: No key table entry found for host/ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal@EXAMPLE.COM while gett...PLE.COM'
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: Success getting keytab entry for nfs/*@EXAMPLE.COM
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM' are good until 1535070934
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM' are good until 1535070934
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: creating tcp client for server kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: creating context with server nfs@kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Failed to create krb5 context for user with uid 0 for server nfs@kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Failed to create machine krb5context with cred cache FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.CO...mple.com
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Failed to create machinekrb5 context with any credentialscache for server kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 00:59:29 ip-10-1-5-59.us-east-2.compute.internal rpc.gssd[32200]: doing error downcall
```

The following logs show up on jourtanctl:

```
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: Success getting keytab entry for nfs/*@EXAMPLE.COM
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM' are good until 1535070934
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM' are good until 1535070934
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: creating tcp client for server kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: creating context with server nfs@kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Failed to create krb5 context for user with uid 0 for server nfs@kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Failed to create machine krb5context with cred cache FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM for server kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Machine cache prematurelyexpired or corrupted trying torecreate cache for server kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: Full hostname for 'kbserver.example.com' is 'kbserver.example.com'
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: Full hostname for 'kbclient.example' is 'kbclient.example'
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: No key table entry found for kbclient$@EXAMPLE.COM while getting keytab entry for 'kbclient$@EXAMPLE.COM'
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: No key table entry found for KBCLIENT$@EXAMPLE.COM while getting keytab entry for 'KBCLIENT$@EXAMPLE.COM'
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: No key table entry found for root/kbclient.example@EXAMPLE.COM while getting keytab entry for 'root/kbclient.example@EXAMPLE.COM'
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: No key table entry found for nfs/kbclient.example@EXAMPLE.COM while getting keytab entry for 'nfs/kbclient.example@EXAMPLE.COM'
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: No key table entry found for host/kbclient.example@EXAMPLE.COM while getting keytab entry for 'host/kbclient.example@EXAMPLE.COM'
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: Success getting keytab entry for nfs/*@EXAMPLE.COM
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM' are good until 1535070934
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: INFO: Credentials in CC 'FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM' are good until 1535070934
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: creating tcp client for server kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: creating context with server nfs@kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Failed to create krb5 context for user with uid 0 for server nfs@kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Failed to create machine krb5context with cred cache FILE:/tmp/krb5ccmachine_EXAMPLE.COM for server kbserver.example.com
Aug 23 01:09:48 kbclient.example rpc.gssd[32200]: WARNING: Failed to create machinekrb5 context with any credentialscache for server kbserver.example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to have a keytab file with the hosts added. I couldn't get it to use `kadmin.local` to use `ktadd` to add it, so I copied it manually.

In the client:

```
echo $BASE_64_ENCODED_FILE_FROM_SERVER | base64 -d > /etc/krb5.keytab
kinit -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab
mkdir -p /home/root/nfs-test/2
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5 kbserver.example.com:/ /home/root/nfs-test/2 --verbose
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Fri Aug 24 01:02:58 2018
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.1,addr=10.1.5.21,clientaddr=10.1.5.59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell. Just in case, did your check your /etc/exports? It should have at least "sec=krb5", e.g:

```
/  10.1.5.0/24(rw,sec=krb5:krb5i:krb5p)
```

Comment: Yeah, it's there. [ec2-user@kbserver ~]$ sudo cat /etc/exports
/home/ec2-user/anypoint-nfs-share     *(rw,sec=krb5,fsid=0,sync,no_root_squash)